# How can I serve different view blocks based on media queries?

Tags: 7, views, theming, blocks

I have 4 view blocks that I want to show up as carousels on mobile. I'd like to be able to clone them, turn the clones into carousels with this module https://www.drupal.org/project/slick, then serve them in place of the others somehow. I know I can use css to serve both and hide them but that doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: That's not the right approach. You should serve the same content to all users, and style it based on media queries; that's what media queries are for, not for helping to decide what HTML should be served in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Browsecap](https://www.drupal.org/project/browscap) and [Browsecap Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/browscap_block) modules to show blocks only on mobile devices.